# Using a variable in a PHP SOAP request

Tags: php, wordpress, soap

I'm having trouble with a variable my PHP SOAP request. $q88Search is the variable. It works perfectly like this

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.q88.com/ws/api.asmx?wsdl');
    $q88Search = "Vessel Name";
    $params = array("AuthorizationString" => "XXXXXX",
                                    "VesselName" => $q88Search);
    $response = $client->__soapCall("GetQ88", array($params));

    echo $response->GetQ88Result;
```

where the variable is the string **Vessel Name** but if I dynamically call the variable from wordpress as a custom field the request fails. Even if the custom field value is the same **Vessel Name** or **"Vessel Name"** (*even included the quotes second time.*)
i.e.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.q88.com/ws/api.asmx?wsdl');
        $q88Search = the_field('q88_search_text');
        $params = array("AuthorizationString" => "XXXXX",
                                        "VesselName" => $q88Search);
        $response = $client->__soapCall("GetQ88", array($params));
        echo $response->GetQ88Result;
```

If I echo $q88Search it outputs correctly as **Vessel Name**. So I believe its some sort of variable string error but I'm a noobie to this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Stewardside, I've edited and removed the '*/' from the code. Sorry That was my error the pasting the question so not relevant. I can't see my error logs. I'm testing on shared hosting. My resulting page just says 'Vessel not found' .

Comment: Ok, I got sorted. 
Still not sure I understand how but it had to do with the way I called the custom field. 
`$client = new SoapClient('http://www.q88.com/ws/api.asmx?wsdl');
$your_custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'q88_search_text', true);
$params = array("AuthorizationString" => "XXXX", VesselName" => $your_custom_field);
$response = $client->__soapCall("GetQ88", array($params));
echo $response->GetQ88Result;`